# textFieldShouldReturn is not working in ipad

Tags: ios4

I am creating an application on IPad. I use a text field with default return key to write message.After writing a message I press return key..Then the keyboard dissappeared, but the method  `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {}`  does NOT get called. I have some code within the `textFieldShouldReturn` function...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[textField resignFirstResponder];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];  
if(cPageNavType == CUTSOM_NAV_BAR){
    mToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 438, 320, 44);
    mTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 340, 400); 
}else {
    mTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 480-44-18-28);
    mToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480-44-18-28, 320, 44);
}
[UIView commitAnimations];

//[self postMessage:nil];
return YES;
}
```

so what can I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set the delegate properly?

Comment: Are you sure method doesn't get called? Did you try a breakpoint or a `NSLog` at the beginning of the method?

Answer (score 0):

**Things to check**

1. Add `<UITextFieldDelegate>` ,make your class receiver of delegate
2. OfCourse add delegate method(put break points)
3. Connect the textfield outlets (delegates and referencing outlets if any)